# What are the pros and cons of adding secondary columns to a table's primary key?

Tags: mysql, index, innodb

In MySQL, I understand that with InnoDB the contents of the primary key get attached to the leaf node of every other index on the table.

I have a `photos` table.  Queries on it come in many different forms, with many different `GROUP`ings, `WHERE` filters on many columns, etc.

As such I have a plethora of indexes on the table.

One thing that holds true though, is that for almost any query on the table, I want to retrieve `filename`.

(I've not made the filename the PK as other tables (`photo_tags` etc) have FK references to the `photo` table, and an auto-incrementing `photoId` column seems a lot more efficient?)

Am I right in thinking that it'd be savvy to make the PRIMARY KEY `(photoId, filename)` so that `filename` is always present in the leaf nodes of any other index lookups?

Sorry if any of my terminology is wrong, I'm far from a DBA expert!

Comment: You may do it. But you must understand that it increases the size of all indexes and decreases data change speed. And the profit for non-covered indexes will be small.

Comment: I do understand that.  I guess I'd like to know if it'd be considered a "best practice", or not.

Comment: Additionally you will have a problem with a FKs - the referent index must be unique, so you must have additional unique index by `(photoId)` to reference to this table.

Comment: I'm not sure that's right @Akina, as the PK can still be UNIQUE given that it's comprised of `photoId` & `filename` and `photoId` is always unique (as is `filename`, but it shouldn't matter if it weren't).

Comment: PK is unique - that's right. But this fact cannot guarantee that a part of (when you create complex PK the FK will refer to a part of it) it is unique. Only unique index can do it.

Comment: _"In MySQL, I understand that with InnoDB the contents of the primary key get attached to the leaf node of every other index on the table."_ : This is referring to [Use of Index Extensions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/index-extensions.html).

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:  The `filename` in `PRIMARY KEY (photoId, filename)` buys you nothing (if I correctly understand your use case).

Long answer (and a lot more tips):

- `AUTO_INCREMENT` needs the id to be the *first* column in *some* index; nothing more.
- The `PRIMARY KEY` is, but definition, UNIQUE.  Adding extra columns changes that uniqueness constraint.  This is likely to hurt in that you can accidentally insert rows that would violate the previous (shorter) PK.
- As far as the disk space for the PK and data (which share the same BTree), there is virtually no change.
- On the other hand, the fatter the PK is, the fatter *secondary* indexes will be.  This is because the PK is implicitly added to each secondary key (as you stated).  Only sometimes does this fattening matter.
- For performance, you need to have the appropriate index.  That is, design the indexes, then see if you can do some minor cleanups.  Example:  `INDEX(a), INDEX(a,b)` --> only `INDEX(a,b)`.
- Indexes should tackle `WHERE`, then `GROUP BY`, then `ORDER BY`.  [*More discussion*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).  (Without specifics, I can't help in more detail.)
- What is retrieved (`SELECT filename, ...`) is rarely a consideration in designing indexes.  Exception: "Covering" index.
- If the Optimizer has decided to use the PK, then adding extra columns to the PK will not help at all.  Adding columns to a secondary index *may* matter.
- It's an old wive's tale that you should avoid varchars for ints in the PK.  It is *sometimes* beneficial *to some degree*.  I would rather discuss specific cases.  A BTree works the same way whether it is ordered by an `INT` or `VARCHAR(99)`.
- We need to see the main queries against the table in order to be more specific.

In one application (and using your photo analogy):  The giant Photos table had an auto_inc `photoID`, but most queries included `WHERE userID = 123`.  So:

```
PRIMARY KEY(photoID),
INDEX(..., userID, ...),
INDEX(..., userID, ...),
INDEX(..., userID, ...),
...
```

Since the data is ordered via the PK, looking up by userID led to jumping around on the disk.  This turned out to be almost twice as fast:

```
PRIMARY KEY(userID, photoID) -- cluster on userid; photoid for uniqueness
INDEX(photoID),   -- kept auto_inc happy
INDEX(..., userID, ...),
INDEX(..., userID, ...),
...   -- fewer were needed
```

The uniqueness constraint on `photoID` was lost, but the `INSERTs` used auto_inc to effectively never violate the constraint.

This table was much too big to be cached in RAM; the speedup mostly came from clustering on userID.

To loop back to your Question...  That suggested change hurts this query:

```
SELECT filename FROM Photos WHERE photoID = 235;  (with no other columns)
```

The simple answer is to change `INDEX(photoID)` into a 'covering' index:  `INDEX(photoID, filename)`.  Note that this does not contradict anything I said above.